# Is there any elegant way to find only symbolic links pointing to directories, not other files?

Tags: find, ls, symlink

`find -type l` and `ls -l | grep '^l'` show symbolic links but do not distinguish between symlinks pointing to directories and those pointing to files. A very kludgy way to do something like this is `find -type l -exec file -L '{}' ';' | grep directory` but that is very inefficient.

Is there a better way to find only symlinks that point to directories?

Comment: `ls -l | grep '^l'` is wrong, it'll fail for files containing `^l` or new lines [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425), https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: There certainly are reasons not to parse `ls`, but that's not one of them.  `grep '^l'` will never match a circumflex followed by a lower-case ell.  You'd have to use `grep '\^l'` or `grep -F '^l'`.

Answer (score 14):

According to [the POSIX specification of `test`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), the `-d` test is:

> True if *pathname* resolves to an existing directory entry for a directory.

So once you have a symlink, use `[ -d ... ]` on it:

```
find . -type l -exec test -d {} \; -print
```

Or, to avoid executing an external command for each link:

```
find . -type l -exec sh -c 'for l; do [ -d "$l" ] && printf "%s\n" "$l"; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Note that whether `[` or `printf` is builtin in sh or not is unspecified by POSIX, `[` generally is, `printf` not always. Running `find -exec test -d {} \;` also may not fork and exec a separate utility like with busybox `find`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `-type l` with `-xtype d`. (I don't know if `-xtype` is POSIX though.)

Comment: I'm afraid [it's not](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html).

Answer (score 3):

For [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) users, this can easily be achieved using the [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `(@-/)`:

```
for F in **/*(N@-/); do the_thing "$F"; done
```

Breaking down that expression: The `**/*` glob matches all files/directories recursively, excluding hidden ones. `(expr)` after the glob limits the match to files satisfying certain criteria. The criteria here are:

- `N`: enable nullglob far that one expansion so that if there's no matching file, it expands to nothing rather than causing an error. You generally want to use that qualifier when the glob is used in a `for` loop or in an array assignment.
- `@`: match only symbolic links
- `-`: switch from testing the links themselves to testing the link *targets*
- `/`: match only directories

Example output, run in `/etc/` on my system:

```
% ls -ldF -- **/*(@-/)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Sep 22  2022 alternatives/desktop-plasma5-wallpaper -> /usr/share/desktop-base/active-theme/wallpaper/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Sep 22  2022 alternatives/desktop-theme -> /usr/share/desktop-base/homeworld-theme/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Sep 22  2022 alternatives/vendor-logos -> /usr/share/desktop-base/debian-logos/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Sep 22  2022 runit/runsvdir/default/ssh -> /etc/sv/ssh/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug  7  2022 xdg/systemd/user -> ../../systemd/user/
```

Note that this also matches links that point to links pointing to directories, not just direct links.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want something that works on (GNU) Linux:

```bash
find -type l -xtype d -print
```

This has the advantage that you can specify some action other than `-print`.

If you need POSIX then perhaps something like this:

```bash
(
export LC_COLLATE=C
find    . -type l -print | sort > ListOfLinks &
find -L . -type d -print | sort > ListOfDirs &
wait
comm -12 ListOfLinks ListOfDirs
)
```

(Refer to the POSIX specs for [find](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), [sort](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html), and [comm](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html).)

Note that this will traverse directories pointed to by symlinks that it finds, so in some cases it will perform worse than your naïve version.

This outputs one path per line, with the usual caveat: it can't work if you have newlines *in* your filenames, so if you need to handle filenames with newlines, you'll need to pick some different tools -- see GNUish method above, or try something like ...

If you have Perl you could write:

```bash
perl -Mv5.10 -MFile::Find -e '
    find( { wanted => sub { -l && -d && say },
            no_chdir => 1 }, @ARGV )
' .
```

(Don't forget the `.` on the end; that's the current directory. Corresponding answers using Python and other languages are left as exercises for the reader; the key point is there's a call-back function that's invoked for each name.)

Comment: In POSIX `find`, the list of files/dirs for `find` to start searching on is not optional. To search the current working directory, use `find .`

Comment: Note that `find -L` will follow those links to directories and start looking for more files recursively in there.

Comment: Note that `LC_ALL` and `LC_COLLATE` take precedence over `LANG`. That `comm`-based approach only works if you can guarantee file paths won't contain newline characters.

Comment: With `perl`, you'd like want `say $File::Find::name` or you'll only get the base names of the matching files.

Comment: `-Mv5.10` is surely less confusing than `-M5.01`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for those reminders; updated accordingly. I'd already noted "the usual caveats about strange filenames", and the wider directory traversal.)

Comment: @ikegami I just realised that the `v5.x.x` notation was added at the same time as `use` _version_, back in v5.6.0, but I missed the ever-so-slightly later update in 5.6.1 where the documentation gave an example of them being used together. So gosh, I've been stuck for 25 years writing `use v5.006` when I could have been using `use v5.6` all along. I'm both embarrassed, and pleased to learn something new. :-(

Comment: I *think* that having `sort` fragment any filenames with embedded newlines only results in mangled output; the matching names are correctly identified, so the overall output is the same as you'd get by doing it "correctly" and then sorting the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version which should be a bit more efficient than `find . -type l -exec test -d {} \; -print` for many links:

```sh
$ find / -type l -print0 |
xargs -0 stat -L -c'%F %n' |
awk '$1 == "directory" { print substr($0, 11) }'
```

It finds all links, feeds them into `stat` to determine the file type, then `awk` filters directories, leaving only the filename.

Without `awk`you get something like:

```text
directory /sys/module/libnvdimm/holders/nfit
```

Verification:

```sh
$ ll /sys/module/libnvdimm/holders/nfit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 20 13:49 /sys/module/libnvdimm/holders/nfit -> ../../nfit
$ readlink -f /sys/module/libnvdimm/holders/nfit
/sys/module/nfit
$ ll -d /sys/module/nfit
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 0 Oct 16 20:45 /sys/module/nfit
```

Comment: Most times when people think they need to write `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 cmd --cmdopt`, they could instead write `find ... -exec cmd -options {} +`. The only time not to do that is if you actually have `find ... -print0 | some other cmds here | xargs -0 cmd -options`. Also, don't forget the `-r` option for `xargs`, because sometimes your `cmd` does unwanted things when invoked with _no_ filenames. (e.g. `ls` defaults to `.`, and output a lot, rather than nothing)

Comment: Note that `find -print0` is a GNUism (so "strictly POSIX" is out) but then you could write `find -type l -printf '%Y %p\0' | grep -z ^d | cut -z -c3-`. (Or of course, `find -type l -xtype d -print0`.)

Comment: I think @MartinKealey's point was that you could just be running `find . -type l -exec stat -L -c'%F %n' {} + |
awk '$1 == "directory" { print substr($0, 11) }'` instead of piping through xargs (in any case any benefit you would have had from `-print0` is immediately lost when piping to ask).

Comment: "to ask" mean "through awk"? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo and should be "when piping to awk"

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

With *rawhide* (*rh*) you can do:

```
rh 'l && td'
```

Or, more verbosely/readably:

```
rh 'link && target_dir'
```

`l` or `link` tests that the current candidate file is a symlink.

`td` or `target_dir` tests that the symlink target is a directory.

Actually, `td`/`target_dir` can't succeed unless the current candidate file is a symlink, so you only need:

```
rh td
```